# Iterating over lists in pandas dataframe to remove everything after certain value in list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to filter my dataframe values based on the occurrence of '1' in my column events.
When a 1 occurres, everything after the 1 should be removed.

This works when I have a singe list:

```
event = [5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5]
index = event.index(1)
event[:index]
```

outputs:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Now I want to do this for my whole dataframe, which looks like this:

```
| session_id | events |
|00000000000 | [4,5,5,3,2,1,5] |
|00000000001 | [4,5,5,1,2,1,5,5,5] |
|00000000002 | [4,5,1,3,2,1,5,5,5,1] |
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['00000000000 ', [4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5]],
                   ['00000000001', [4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5]],
                   ['00000000002 ', [4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1]]],
                  columns=['session_id', 'events'])
```

---

But I cannot seem to  get it right. Is someone able to help me?
My final solution was to do this:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    target_id = row['events'].index(1)
    df['events_short'] = row['events'][:target_id]
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Fix

Your `df['events_short'] =`  means setting a new whole column, which isn't what you want, you need to set only one cell

```
df['events_short'] = ""
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, 'events_short'] = row['events'][:row['events'].index(1)]
```

or overwrite

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, 'events'] = row['events'][:row['events'].index(1)]
```

---

#### Improve

You can also use `Series.apply` to apply your logic on each cell of the columns

```
df['events'] = df['events'].apply(lambda x: x[:x.index(1)])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Both solutions work. I only have one issue left, which I didn't think of yet. In some rows, the 1 does not occur. What to do when that happens, because now I'll get an error.