# Iterating over lists in pandas dataframe to remove everything after certain value (if the value exists) in list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, iteration

I want to filter my dataframe values based on the occurrence of '1' in my column events. When a 1 occurres, everything after the 1 should be removed.

I want to do this for my whole dataframe, which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['00000000000 ', [4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5]],
                   ['00000000001', [4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5]],
                   ['00000000002 ', [4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1]]],
                  columns=['session_id', 'events'])
```

This works with the following solution, like answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932123/iterating-over-lists-in-pandas-dataframe-to-remove-everything-after-certain-valu).

```
df['events_short'] = ""
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, 'events_short'] = row['events'][:row['events'].index(1)]
```

This only works if the '1' occurs, when it doesn't, I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-e4d3f228e32f> in <module>()
      1 df['events_short'] = ""
      2 for i, row in df.iterrows():
----> 3     df.at[i, 'events_short'] = row['events'][:row['events'].index(1)]

ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

Therefore, I need an exception, for when the 1 does not occur in the array. Can someone help me to set this up? Thanks!

Comment: Please share a reproducible code and dataframe and edit your question

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @OnY's answer is nice, it requires to read twice each list (once to find if the index is existing, once to find it).

A more efficient approach might be to use a helper function with `try`/`except`:

```
def upto1(l):
    try:
        return l[:l.index(1)]
    except ValueError:
        return l
    
df['events2'] = df['events'].apply(upto1)
```

example:

```
    session_id                          events          events2
0  00000000000           [4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5]  [4, 5, 5, 3, 2]
1  00000000001     [4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5]        [4, 5, 5]
2  00000000002  [4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1]           [4, 5]
3  00000000003                       [0, 2, 3]        [0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @Oldbighorn you don't have to accept my answer, you can keep that of Ony, this was more of a general comment, the true gain in speed should be checked in a real use-case

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` and find the first element in the list, and truncate it accordingly.

```
df['events_short']=df['events'].apply(lambda x:x[0:x.index(1)] if 1 in x else None)
```

If you want to include the 1:

```
df['events_short']=df['events'].apply(lambda x:x[0:x.index(1)+1] if 1 in x else None)
```

Note that `apply` as preferred (faster) than `iterrow`

Comment: When I try this, I only get 'None' values, with an error message: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @Oldbighorn I get no error, and None only where there are no 1 in the list. Try to open a new console and make sure you are using the exact example you uploaded and my code.

Comment: Allright! thanks a lot, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Building further off of @mozway's answer, it is (generally) good practice to avoid having the program intentionally raise an exception and catching, since the try-except can be slower than non-failing logic:

```
def upto1(l):
    return l[:l.index(1)] if 1 in l else l

df['events2'] = df['events'].apply(upto1)
```